# I am getting a timeout error with WinRM. Please can someone explain what is wrong with my script?

Tags: powershell, packer

I am trying to build a Windows AMI bootstrapped against a PowerShell script, but I keep getting a timeout error for WinRM.

I've also tried switching the communicator to SSH but that didn't work so I went back to WinRM as it made more sense to use this for what I am trying to achieve.

This is my Packer JSON script:

```json
{
  "builders": [
    {
      "access_key": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
      "secret_key": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "ami_name": "WINCIS-Hardened-{{timestamp}}",
      "instance_type": "t2.micro",
      "type": "amazon-ebs",
      "source_ami": "ami-016ed249dc46e6b40",
      "associate_public_ip_address":"True",
      "communicator": "winrm",
      "winrm_username": "Administrator",
      "winrm_port": "5986",
      "winrm_timeout": "15m",
      "winrm_use_ssl" :"true",
      "winrm_insecure": "true",
      "region": "eu-west-2",
      "vpc_id": "vpc-XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "subnet_id": "subnet-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    }
  ],
  "provisioners": [
    {
      "type": "powershell",
      "execute_command": "powershell -executionpolicy bypass \"& { if (Test-Path variable:global:ProgressPreference='SilentlyContinue'};. '{{.Path}}'; exit \\$LastExitCode }\"",
      "script": "./wincis_hardened.ps1"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
$ packer build wincis_hardened_aws.json
amazon-ebs output will be in this color.

==> amazon-ebs: Prevalidating AMI Name: WINCIS-Hardened-1566374649
amazon-ebs: Found Image ID: ami-016ed249dc46e6b40
==> amazon-ebs: Creating temporary keypair: packer_5d5cfaf9-bd9b-284e-128a-993f4749f7b2
==> amazon-ebs: Creating temporary security group for this instance: packer_5d5cfafa-b6d8-c968-12a3-f293dd2a04e9
==> amazon-ebs: Authorizing access to port 5986 from [0.0.0.0/0] in the temporary security groups...
==> amazon-ebs: Launching a source AWS instance...
==> amazon-ebs: Adding tags to source instance
amazon-ebs: Adding tag: "Name": "Packer Builder"
amazon-ebs: Instance ID: i-08ac611d79b8ecba7
==> amazon-ebs: Waiting for instance (i-08ac611d79b8ecba7) to become ready...
==> amazon-ebs: Waiting for auto-generated password for instance...
amazon-ebs: It is normal for this process to take up to 15 minutes,
amazon-ebs: but it usually takes around 5. Please wait.
amazon-ebs:
amazon-ebs: Password retrieved!
==> amazon-ebs: Using winrm communicator to connect: 35.178.131.180
==> amazon-ebs: Waiting for WinRM to become available...
==> amazon-ebs: Timeout waiting for WinRM.
==> amazon-ebs: Terminating the source AWS instance...
==> amazon-ebs: Cleaning up any extra volumes...
==> amazon-ebs: No volumes to clean up, skipping
==> amazon-ebs: Deleting temporary security group...
==> amazon-ebs: Deleting temporary keypair...
Build 'amazon-ebs' errored: Timeout waiting for WinRM.

==> Some builds didn't complete successfully and had errors:
--> amazon-ebs: Timeout waiting for WinRM.

==> Builds finished but no artifacts were created.
```

Comment: PLEASE, fix your code formatting >>> Markdown Editing Help - Stack Overflow — https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code <<< and then trim your post down to the minimal needed to demo the problem >>> How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example - Help Center - Stack Overflow — https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example <<<

Comment: Can you manually connect to 35.178.131.180:5986 or 35.178.131.180:5985?

Comment: Maybe also check the certificate presented by `:5986`

Comment: Hi, I've tried connecting manually but I've not been able to. Doing some digging around I've found that using WinRM seems to be plagued with issues. I've come across the following article so I'll see where it gets it when I follow it. But the gist of it is, WinRM is likely not configured on the instance and so they attempt to bootstrap it with a script to configure WinRM first..... https://blog.petegoo.com/2016/05/10/packer-aws-windows/

Answer (score 0):

in my case is was a firewall issue. port "5986" is blocked on firewall.

Make sure you can telnet WinRM port from your PC!

I set "winrm_port" : 443 
and used below snippet in user_data.sh.

`cmd.exe /c winrm set "winrm/config/listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTPS" "@{Port="443";Hostname="packer";CertificateThumbprint="$($Cert.Thumbprint)"}"`

cmd.exe /c netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="remote administration" new enable=yes

cmd.exe /c netsh firewall add portopening TCP 443 "Port 443"